# Инициализация массива! (java)

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть входной файл, там число `0<j<100000;`
`int` мне не подходит, т.к. больше 32656. значит делаю `long j`.

Пишу `String m[] = new String[j];`, выдает ошибку, что нужен `int`.

Что делать?

Answer (score 3):

Ну int, на самом деле, вмещает гораздо больше, чем 35656, т.к. int в java 32 битный, то `int_maxvalue = 2^32-1 = 2,147,483,647`, спокойно меняйте long на int